# Akira not replaced to 明

Tags: gedit, internationalization, input-language

If i changed keyboard layout to "Chineese" and start gedit,

```
"aki-ra" or "akira" its not replaced to 明.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion of input text into CJK scripts does not make use of keyboard layouts; instead, it requires special input methods. Launch *Keyboard Input Methods* and open the "Input Methods" tab. You can add input methods from the "Select an input method" dropdown. Subsequently, you can switch your input method using the little keyboard icon in the upper right.

[image: iBus Keyboard Input Methods screenshot]

By the way アキラ is Japanese, not Chinese script.

Comment: +1 for "not Chinese but Japanese"

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards "Keyboard Input Methods" in german is "Tastatureingabemethoden". The Applicationname i ment was "ibus-setup".